# Google Form to Document Merge to Pdf to Mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I think my issue is in the `e.values` I am using along with the `('keyXXXXX', XXXXX);` that I am using.

The original code I used was something I borrowed from TJ Houston's site.  I am using it for an application process.  I wrote the code following the process of using

```
var last_name = e.values [1]
```

and matching it with the

```
copyBody.replaceText('keyLastName', last_name);
```

It worked for most of the entries but failed on

```
var emergency_phone = e.values[23];
```

matched with

```
copyBody.replaceText('keyEmergencyContactPhone', emergency_phone);
```

On that form and code I had over 100 lines of Var and CopyBody matches.  I created a simpler one to test, which fails as soon as you get to cphone.

```
// LAC Employement Applicaiton Script based on TJ Houston tjhouston.com   (tj@tjhouston.com)
// LAC Employment Application
// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "1Vb0P03a6qPfJOvo_bP_3zUM159XP18c3tfBL62L_mIs"; // *** replace with your template ID ***
var docName = "Applicaiton Review";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var email_address = "jreach@gmail.com";
var last_name = e.values[1];
var first_name = e.values[2];
var middle_name = e.values[3];
var current_address = e.values[4];
var ccity = e.values[5];
var cstate = e.values[6];
var czip = e.values[7];
var years = e.values[8];
var home_phone = e.values[9];
var cphone = e.values[10];
var email = e.values[11];
var emergency_contact = e.values[12];
var ephone = e.values[13];  



// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+last_name)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('key1', last_name);
copyBody.replaceText('key2', first_name);
copyBody.replaceText('key3', middle_name);
copyBody.replaceText('key4', current_address);
copyBody.replaceText('key5', ccity);
copyBody.replaceText('key6', cstate);
copyBody.replaceText('key7', czip);
copyBody.replaceText('key8', years);
copyBody.replaceText('key8', home_phone);
copyBody.replaceText('key9', cphone);
copyBody.replaceText('key10', email);
copyBody.replaceText('key11', emergency_contact);
copyBody.replaceText('key12', ephone);

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Applicaiton Review";
var body = "You have received an application from " + last_name + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Figured out the issue...although i would love for someone to explain the correct parameters.  Google Docs (key) must be unique.  When using the numbers it was only ready the first number...i.e. 10 became Key 1 and then it used 0 as the data.  When I changed 10 to be CellPhone it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when replacing multiple keys in a document you are quite right that the keys must be unique.  Personally I bracket all keys with # symbols which works for me e.g. #key1# won't be confused with #key10#